# Why can't an electron emit more than 1 photon when moving down from an excited state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photoelectric-effect

Why is the following statement false?

When an electron loses energy in making a transition from one state to another, energy is conserved by several photons being emitted.

I don't see which conservation law this violates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This process is perfectly possible; it's just very unlikely, because of the details of how atoms couple to the electromagnetic field.

If you want a concrete example, the simplest case is the 2s-1s transition in hydrogen, for which single-photon mechanisms are forbidden by symmetry, but which will still decay via a two-photon route. The decay rate is about nine orders of magnitude slower than normal radiative decay in hydrogen, but it's nevertheless nonzero.

Comment: " for which single-photon mechanisms are forbidden by symmetry, but which will still decay via a two-photon route." I don't quite understand what you are saying there sorry Ive only just started studying quantum physics.

Comment: The details don't matter. This particular transition happens to be forbidden as a single-photon process because of symmetry considerations. This allows the two-photon decay, which would otherwise be a negligible correction, to dominate the dynamics.

Answer (score -1):

The electron isnt traveling from one energy state to another, he literally cant be between energy levels , which means the diffrence of energy between those two levels have to be somewhere , when you calculate the diffrence you basiclly see its an energy of one photon with a specific frequency , and only this frequency match the diffrence. This is aprroved by the spectrum emmiting from this atom
If an electron is falling few levels ,one by one , its gonna emmit a photon for every level - which the photon frequency is gonna match the diffrence of energy between each level

Answer (score -1):

It's because all possible states which quantum systems (for example atom with electron/s)  could be are allways discrete sets. (It's one of quantum mechanics principles)

This means - if you want change energy state of something, you can make it only in "steps".

Knowing this, emission of more than 2 photons means - system has to make two "steps" - emission more than one photon from atom indicates exisiting of 2 states.

2s-1s transition in hydrogen isn't emission of 2 photons from one state, it's just states beeing extremly close to each other and one of them (first) has very little time of life.

Summarizing - it's isnt violating any conservation law, but quantum mechanics principles - which means that maybe it is possible, but you can't use Schrodinger equation (and generally any quantum equation/theory) to observe or predict that phenomena.

Comment: "2s-1s transition in hydrogen isn't emission of 2 photons from one state, it's just states beeing extremly close to each other and one of them (first) has very little time of life" $-$ this is about as wrong as it's possible to be. The states are far apart in energy (10.2 eV, with the largest possible transition between bound states in hydrogen being 13.6 eV), and they are two of the most stable states in hydrogen (1s is the ground state; the 2s is a metastable state with a lifetime of about 0.12 s [arXiv:0705.3033], as compared to nanosecond lifetimes for typical transitions.

Comment: Ok, after consideration (and some reading : ) ), I have to admit that you are right. Not only energy gap plays role here, but conservation of angular momentum too.